# ggplot2 equivalent of 'factorization or categorization' in googleVis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-visualization, googlevis

Due to static graph prepared by ggplot, we are shifting our graphs to googleVis with interactive charts. But when it comes to categorization we are facing many problems. Let me give example which will help you understand:

```
#dataframe
df = data.frame( x = sample(1:100), y = sample(1:100), cat = sample(c('a','b','c'), 100, replace=TRUE) )
```

ggplot2 provides parameter like `alpha, colour, linetype, size` which we can use with categories like shown below:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = cat))
```

Not just line chart, but majority of ggplot2 graphs provide categorization based on column values. Now I would like to do the same in googleVis, based on value `df$cat` I would like parameters to get changed or grouping of line or charts.

Note:
I have already tried `dcast` to make multiple columns based on category column and use those multiple columns as Y input, but that it not what I would like to do.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'm not familair with R, but in the general javascript implementation of the Google Visualization API, all data series are defined by columns, not by values in a column.  You will likely have to split your data into multiple columns to get the effect you want.

Comment: Thats why I have put this question... There might be a way around in R... May be using other package?

Comment: You can create interactive ggplot graphs with [plotly](http://ropensci.org/blog/2014/04/17/plotly/)

Comment: @vrajs5 -please take a look at the solution posted to your old question using  `myvar.style` as extra column to get more out of googleVis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*vrajs5* you are not alone! We struggled with this issue. In our case we wanted to `fill` bar charts like in ggplot. This is the solution. You need to **add specifically named columns, linked to your variables**, to your data table for `googleVis` to pick up.

In my fill example, these are called **roles**, but once you see my syntax you can abstract it to annotations and other cool features. Google has them all [documented here (check out superheroes example!)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) but it was not obvious how it applied to [r](/questions/tagged/r).

@mages has this documented on this webpage, which shows features not in `demo(googleVis)`:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html

**EXAMPLE ADDING NEW DIMENSIONS TO GOOGLEVIS CHARTS**

```
# in this case
# How do we fill a bar chart showing bars depend on another variable? 
#   We wanted to show C in a different fill to other assets

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(googleVis))
library(data.table) # You can use data frames if you don't like DT

test.dt  = data.table(px = c("A","B","C"), py = c(1,4,9),
                      "py.style" = c('silver', 'silver', 'gold'))

# Add your modifier to your chart as a new variable e.g. py1.style
test <-gvisBarChart(test.dt, 
                    xvar = "px",
                    yvar = c("py", "py.style"),
                    options = list(legend = 'none'))
plot(test)
```

We have shown `py.style` deterministically here, but you could code it to be dependent on your categories.

The secret is *myvar.googleVis_thing_youneed* linking the variable *myvar* to the googleVis feature.

**RESULT BEFORE FILL (yvar = "py")**
[image: GoogleVisBarChartBeforeRoleStyleExample]

**RESULT AFTER FILL (yvar = c("py", "py.style"))**

[image: GoogleVisBarChartRoleStyleExample]

Take a look at mages examples (code also on [Github](https://github.com/mages/googleVis/blob/master/demo/Roles.R)) and you will have cracked the "categorization based on column values" issue.