# Mapping variable values to colors in gvisLineChart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, googlevis

I'm looking for the **equivalent** of:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=var1,**group=col1,colour=col1**))+geom_line()
```

in the `googleVis` package.

Anyone knows how to do this? I only found examples of differently colored lines if they are mapping different columns from the `dataframe`.

thanks!

Comment: Don't know if you can do this directly, but you can always `dcast` your data frame to make a column per line you want to plot.

Comment: yes, seems like it. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@mtoto*, I hope my answer here on [ggplot2 equivalent of 'factorization or categorization' in googleVis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30508890/4606130) can help. Have you taken a look?

Using roles you can specify specific styles for your data. It involves adding another column with the style detail. So if plotting `varx`, you need to add the column `varx.style` where you will set the colors.

I do not know ggplot well enough to know if this is the exact fit of what you want, but please take a look at my figures and links in that answer.

Comment: Hi micstr, thanks for the workaround! I find myself working with googlevis less and less however, as it is not as intuitive and easy-to-use than ggplot or ggvis.

Comment: Thanks @mtoto - I might give `ggvis` a whirl as `googleVis` is creating some graphic hiccups with axes on Chrome