# similar to ggplot options in googlevis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, googlevis

Example from R graphics cookbook pg 55.

`ggplot(tg, aes(x=factor(dose), y=length, colour=supp, group=supp)) + geom_line()`

Looking for a similar plotting options in googlevis, on how to specify the  fill options or color option which is a factor variable.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my answer for [ggplot2 equivalent of 'factorization or categorization' in googleVis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733904/ggplot2-equivalent-of-factorization-or-categorization-in-googlevis-in-r/30508890#30508890). 
It has diagrams and examples.

What you are looking for is called **roles** in `goooglevis` and involving appending data columns with set names and linked to your variables. For example, if your variable is `py` you will add a column `py.style` where you set the fill colours.

@mages has this documented on this webpage, which shows features not in demo(googleVis):

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html

All the best, micstr

Comment: All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

Comment: All series on a given axis must be of the same data type  I am getting the following error, also

Comment: I dont have data so I cannot recreate this. Google this "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type" on SO as I see there others with this problem [here see @asgallant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22488369/4606130) and see answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13216377/4606130). Its not all `R` but may give clues.

Comment: I am getting the following error,(All series on a given axis must be of the same data type,) also  my data frame is of the below type.
category vCurveVal date_diff
2015-1  53   0
2014-1  52   1
2013-3  51   3
2012-4  50   2
2015-1  55   0
2014-2  54   1
2013-3  53   5
2012  57   7

I want the date_diff column in the x - axis
v_curve value on the y axis and category as different color lines.

Comment: Your last 2012 data is not like the others, has no -# at end, are you treating these as dates or strings?

Comment: 2012 57 7  (2012 is the group which the data belongs to). 2012 is a factor variable(strings)