# how to set colors of columns in googleCharts?

Tags: r, google-visualization, shiny

```
  gvisColumnChart(df,options = list(gvis.editor="Edit this chart!",width=500,height=500,colors=df$Color))
```

How do I put a vector to state that, what colors I want of the columns in my chart?

Comment: what's in df, your question is not reproducible, also this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30508890/4964651

Comment: df$color has the following data

 "NA"      "#AE6B14" "NA"      "#D5663D" "NA"

Answer (score 0):

Go through this Link

```
chart.draw(data, {
  width: 400,
  height: 240,
  title: 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza',
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'],
  is3D: true
});
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts